# copy_from_user throws unable to handle kernel paging request

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

I'm trying to read/write kernel memory with a module, and so far the read part was working.
I have a program from userspace which opens a device my module created, and can read n bytes from a x addr (kernel memory addr) and this works (is using copy_to_user).
I also confirmed it by reading the same addr with gdb:

`gdb /bin/ls /proc/kcore
 x/2b [addr]`

The problem comes when I try to write to the same memory addr.
Once I try this I get:

`BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at [addr]` 
(same addr i was reading at)
I must say that I took this addr from /proc/kallsyms.

The thing is disturbing me is that I though that we map physical memory into kernel memory, and that means that even if we don't have enough memory to map all our physical memory, at least the range which is mapped to kernel memory should be present, and that if I was able to read from that addr, that means that actually this addr is present right now.

Here the code:

```
            case IOCTL_WRITE_KERNEL_MEMORY:

            pr_info ("%s: IOCTL_WRITE_KERNEL_MEMORY\n", r2_devname);

            if (data->addr < PAGE_OFFSET) {
                    pr_info ("%s: error - 0x%lx belongs to USERSPACE\n", r2_devname, (unsigned long)data->addr);
                    ret = -EINVAL;
                    return ret;
            }

            pr_info ("%s: addr: 0x%lx\n", r2_devname, (unsigned long)data->addr);

            ret = copy_from_user ((void *)data->addr, data->buff, len);
            if (ret) {
                    pr_info ("error: copy_from_user failed\n");
                    ret = -EINVAL;
                    return ret;
            }
            break;
```

data->addr contains the addr, and data->buff the content to read. That is passed through a pointer from userspace:

```
            case WRITE_KERNEL_MEMORY:

            if (argc < 4) {
                    printf ("specify bytes to write\n");
                    break;
            }

            unsigned char c = 0xd;
            data.buff = &c;
            data.addr = 0xf8350000;
            data.len = n_bytes;

            printf ("ioctl: going to write: 0x%x\n", c);
            printf ("ioctl: going to write: 0x%x\n", *data.buff);

            ioctl_n = _IOR (R2_TYPE, 0x2, sizeof (struct r2k_data));
            ret = ioctl (fd, ioctl_n, &data);
            break;
```

and the struct:

```
struct r2k_data {
        unsigned long *addr;
        unsigned long len;
        unsigned char *buff;
};
```

I think that if I could read from that addr, I should be able to write too, and even if i'm not able because of write protection, I think I should get another error message.

Someone has an idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: `I think that if I could read from that addr, I should be able to write too, and even if i'm not able because of write protection, I think I should get another error message.` - No, memory accessible for read doesn't need to be accessible for write. And writting to *readonly* memory region **within kernel** cause *common* error message `unable to handle kernel paging request at`; there is no specific message for that case.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev, do you know how can I check if an addr is write-protected? Maybe checking some of the PG_flags from include/linux/page-flags.h ?
Thanks

Comment: Before checking flags, you should **find** page descriptor for the desired address. What type of information do you expect to find at given address? E.g., kernel code usually is write-protected, same for global data marked as `const` in the code.

Comment: I found the page descriptor with virt_to_page. Actually this it's just a a test. At this addr (the addr i'm reading at) the function native_read_cr4 is placed. I don't expect to find anything special, just that I could read from that addr, and I was curious if I could write to that addr too. Anyway, I'd like to test if an address is writeable or not before trying it. I'm looking at the PG_* flags but from the name I can't find the right one.
Thanks.

Comment: I found that the only different between the addr from "native_read_cr4" function and the addre from a variable created inside of a module is that the addr from native_read_cr4 holds PG_reserved, while the other no. So I think I could check if an addr is writeable by checking this bit.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but given the VMA pointer, you can check/set  protection bits for all pages in the VMA as follows: include/linux/mm.h: 
pgprot_t vm_get_page_prot(unsigned long vm_flags);
void vma_set_page_prot(struct vm_area_struct *vma);
Notice the param is the VMA flags member.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just read or write arbitrary addresses! Whether for read or for write, all addresses have to be "mapped", i.e., marked as usable by the kernel and with sufficient permissions for you to carry out the operation.

For your particular scenario:
a) the read() worked because the destination address 'data.buff' was mapped and allocated to your usermode process context (the running app).
b) the write() fails because :
src is

```
data.addr = 0xf8350000;
```

This is an arbitrary kernel virtual address; you cannot "just" access it!
To do so, why don't you allocate a kernel buffer (with kmalloc or vmalloc) and treat *it's* address as the destination address. It is now a valid and maped kernel memory location. Pseudo-code:

```
 to_addr = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
  <out of memory check>
 ret = copy_from_user ((void *)to_addr, data->buff, len);
 ...
 kfree(to_addr);
```

Comment: It's not an arbitrary addr. Btw, the read operation is performed in this way:
`
                ret = copy_to_user (data->buff, (void *)data->addr, len);
                if (ret) {
                        pr_info ("error: copy_to_user failed\n");
                        ret = -EINVAL;
                        return ret;
                }
`

and data->addr points to the same kernel addr i'm using in the write operation. I think as @Tsyvarev mentioned, has to do more with the perms. Anyway, thank you ;)